# Table in R takes wrong form

Tags: r

I want to make a table in R with the days of the week and percentages. Both are saved in a vector (and of length 7 obviously) but when I try to make a table with 2 colums, the first column being the days and the second column being the percentages, R messes up the table. How can this be solved?
Code:

```
data <-read.csv("IDOlaad_weekdagen.csv")
data.frame(data)
dag = c(data$Dag)
jaar = c(data$Sessies_2014)
najaar = c( data$Sessies_Najaar_2014)
jaarprocent <- round(jaar / sum(jaar) *100, digits = 2)
najaarprocent <- round(najaar / sum(najaar) *100, digits = 2)
table(dag,jaarprocent)
```

The link shows the exact result of my code

Comment: The purpose of the `table` function is to create contingency tables. You are trying to put two vectors together in a table as columns. You may want to try `data.frame()` or `cbind()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide reproducible data using `dput()` so we can repeat your results. You should also read the manual page for any function that is not doing what you expect to see if you are using it properly (in this case `?table`). As @Jan points out, the function is for contingency tables. Here are some data that might be similar yours and a way to get the results you want:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- 1:7
y <- sample(1:10, 7)
ypct <- round(y/sum(y) * 100, 2)
tbl <- data.frame(x, ypct)
print(tbl, row.names=FALSE)
#  x  ypct
#  1  2.78
#  2 13.89
#  3 27.78
#  4 22.22
#  5  5.56
#  6 11.11
#  7 16.67
```